# How to use Fastlane to enable capabilities in provision profile?

Tags: xcode, code-signing, fastlane, code-signing-entitlements, fastlane-match

Our org uses Fastlane to manage out codesign stuff. We have the github repo set up and been using it for a while.

For Xcode13 we added time sensitive usernotifications capability to our entitlement file.

```
  <key>com.apple.developer.usernotifications.time-sensitive</key>
  <true/>
```

From my research it seems like we have to re-generate the provision profile. How can I achieve this with Fastlane?

is using [sigh](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sigh/) the right way? I am hesitating to do any actions because all the iOS dev share the certificate git repo, so I am being very cautious.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me

1. update the entitlements in provisioning profile, log into the Apple developer site and go to the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" section. Select Application IDs on the left, and find the app ID for the app you are trying to build. Click the edit button and turn on the entitlement for Time Sensative User Notification (or whatever you need to add)
2. Run Fastlane match to regenerate the profiles
   `fastlane run match type:"<enterprise or development>" git_branch:"<internal or production>" generate_apple_certs:"false" git_url:"<link to your fastlane cert repo>"` then follow the prompt.